# schema .pre('save') does not trigger

Tags: mongoose

Hi I plan to print out `pre`after pre method triggered,but it does not work.

```
import mongoose from'mongoose'
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('connected')
});

// test for pre hooks
const toySchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String, created: Date });
const Toy = mongoose.model('Toy', toySchema)

toySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (!this.created) this.created = new Date;
  console.log('pre');
  next(new Error('something went wrong'));
});

const firstoy = new Toy({ name: 'tank' })
firstoy.save(function (err, firstoy) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

find the write answer:Define Middleware Before Compiling Models

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#defining